# Count keys inside of hash that have specific value

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash that looks like:

```
day = {
  :morning => true,
  :afternoon => false,
  :evening => true,
  :night => true
}
```

I'd like to get the percent of values that == `true`

I'm current doing

```
sum = day.count.to_f
adherence_percent = (day.select{|k, v| v == true }.count / sum) * 100
:> 66.6666666
```

Is there a more elegant/efficient way I can do this?

Comment: `day.count { |k,v| v }.fdiv day.size`

Comment: `day.reduce(0) { |m, (k,v)|  v ? m.next : m }.fdiv day.size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `count` and `last`

```
day.count(&:last).fdiv(day.size)
```

#### [Demonstration](https://repl.it/NOXS/1)

Comment: that's really clean. I didn't realize you could pass `count` a block. Trying to figure out what `.last` is being called on. How is this working

Comment: When calling Enumerable methods on hashes you get `[key,value]` as an argument if your block has an arity of 1, that is it accepts only one argument. If you specify two you get `key,value`. `last` here calls the second element in the key/value pair array, or `value`.

Comment: and by default is it only counting values that are `true`?

Comment: All the truthy values. Values that are not nil nor false.

Answer (score 2):

If you know there are only true/false values in there

```
day.values.count(&:itself)
```

otherwise

```
day.values.count { |item| item == true }
```

usage:

```
sum = day.count.to_f
adherence_percent = day.values.count(&:itself) / sum * 100
```

Comment: This is half the answer as the question does ask for the percentage.

Comment: Sure? I don't know, the title is different, he talks just about the counting part

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of use `itself` in that way. Such ruby.